# Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I'am developing for a report system based on google maps and i want to show google map data such as car time and speed on a google chart and here is my code:

```js
function updatereport() {
  //alert("aaa");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getreport.php',
    data: {
      yy: '18',
      mm: '05',
      dd: '17',
      hh: '18',
      driverid: '7'
    },
    type: 'get',
    error: function() {
      alert("some error ! :(");
    },
    success: function(result) {
      //alert(result);
      var myobj = JSON.parse(result);

      google.charts.load('visualization', {
        '1.0': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(myobj));

    } //func 
  }) //ajax
}
// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart(myobj) {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  alert("a");
  data.addColumn("number", "time");
  data.addColumn("number", "speed");
  data.addRow();
  for (i in myobj)
    data.addRows(myobj[i].time);


  //var xx=[['T', 'H'],[2, 8.2],[3, .2],[4, 4],[6, 2],[9, 8]];
  //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(xx);
  //alert(myobj[1].time);
  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {
    'title': 'My Average Day',
    'width': 550,
    'height': 400
  };

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

but the problem is when i run this code it shows

> Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined

Comment: The code you copied looks OK, but it can't be enough to do the whole thing, since you don't show how you load the loader and call updatereport.  I would suspect you also have some other way of calling drawChart before the charts code has finished loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the load statement doesn't look correct,

replace this...

```
  google.charts.load('visualization', {
    '1.0': ['corechart']
  });
```

with this...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: There is actually an undocumented feature that interprets "1.0" as the same as "current", so either way should work.

Comment: Right, for what I was suggesting, it would have to be: google.charts.load('1.0', { packages: ['corechart'] } ) .  Without the 'packages' property, nothing would load.  We should probably output an error on the console for bad input.